# SFAuthorizationView - Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, authorization

How use SFAuthorizationView in a swift project. I already tried by creating  a bridging header and imported SecurityInterface/SFAuthorizationView.h . My code is given below.

> My reference   -https://github.com/dominikhofacker/SFAuthorizationView.

The Authorization View and lock icon appeared on my output screen. But when i click on the lock button nothing happens.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var auth: SFAuthorizationView!

@IBOutlet weak var button: NSButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    var items = [ AuthorizationItem(name: kAuthorizationRuleIsAdmin, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0), ]
    var rights = AuthorizationRights(count: UInt32(items.count), items: &items)
            auth.setAuthorizationRights(&rights)
    auth.setDelegate(self)
    auth.updateStatus(nil)
    button.isEnabled = isUnlocked()

}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func isUnlocked() -> Bool {
    return auth.authorizationState() == SFAuthorizationViewUnlockedState;
}


override func authorizationViewDidAuthorize(_ view: SFAuthorizationView!) {
    button.isEnabled = isUnlocked()
}
override func authorizationViewDidDeauthorize(_ view: SFAuthorizationView!) {
    button.isEnabled = isUnlocked()
}
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    print("hihi")
}

}
```

Comment: Please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/securityinterface/sfauthorizationview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just forgot to disable [sandbox mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) at *Capabilities* tab of your project *target*